# How can I split a string into a struct?

Tags: c

I want to get a list of all substring separated by "," and put each into a struct.
e.g if i receive "connor,michel" i want to put "connor" in `struct[0].name` and "michel" in `struct[1].name`. for now I have this:

```
struct crit
{
    char* titre;
    char* noms;
    int annees;
    float cote;
};

char * les_noms = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
int i = 0;
    char *item = strtok(noms, ",");
    
    while(item != NULL)
    {
        les_noms[i++] = item;
        printf("un nom = %s\n", item);
        item = strtok(NULL, ",");
        
    }
```

sorry for the french words.
edit: maked up my mind about `les_nom`

Comment: You defined `les_noms` twice in two different ways. Make up your mind.

Comment: `char * les_noms = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));` is not how you allocate string, the other one was right `char les_noms[50];` the first one just allocate a pointer (probably 4 or 8 bytes) which is not usefull

Comment: Do you have a file that you are reading from? Because your code seems to only allocate les_nom, but never reads any data into it. Where is that (comma-separated) data coming from?

Comment: There is no `noms` for `strtok(noms, ...)`. How about piecing together a [mcve] ? Or.. is this all you got, and that's the problem?

Comment: `char * les_noms = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));` - Wrong!!!!

You want `char * les_noms = malloc(MY_STRING_LENGTH);`

Comment: hi everyone, I'll read a CSV file but the comma-separated data is an argument which is given by the user (i.e. I could call main -t connor,michaell). Here is just some part of my code but I could give you all my code which is about 80 line of code!

Comment: @alexilas I think it would be better if you read some other questions here about csv files in c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person
{
    char *name;
};

int main()
{
    
    
    struct person *persons = NULL;
    int num_persons = 0;

    
    
    char names[80] = "joana,cleiton,márcio,elana,joão";
    const char sep[2] = ",";
    char *item = strtok(names, sep);


    while (item != NULL)
    {
        persons = realloc(persons, ++num_persons * sizeof(struct person));

        persons[num_persons - 1].name = malloc(strlen(item)) + 1;
        strcpy(persons[num_persons - 1].name, item);

        
        item = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_persons; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, persons[i].name);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_persons; i++)
    {
        free(persons[i].name);
    }
    free(persons);
}
```

Or the fixed size solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person
{
    char *name;
};

int main()
{
    
    char names[80] = "joana,cleiton,márcio,elana,joão";
    const char sep[2] = ",";

    unsigned int num_persons = 1;
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(names); i++)
    {
        if (names[i] == ',')
        {
            num_persons++;
        }
    }
    

    struct person persons[num_persons];

    
    char *item = strtok(names, sep);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; item != NULL; i++)
    {
        persons[i].name = malloc(strlen(item) + 1);
        strcpy(persons[i].name, item);
        
        item = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_persons; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, persons[i].name);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_persons; i++)
    {
        free(persons[i].name);
    }
    
}
```

You probally will need more items in the struct, it is easy, look:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person
{
    char *name;
    int len_name;
    int id;
};

int main()
{

    char names[80] = "joana,cleiton,márcio,elana,joão";
    const char sep[2] = ",";

    unsigned int num_persons = 1;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(names); i++)
    {
        if (names[i] == ',')
        {
            num_persons++;
        }
    }


    struct person persons[num_persons];


    char *item = strtok(names, sep);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; item != NULL; i++)
    {
        persons[i].name = malloc(strlen(item) + 1);
        persons[i].len_name = strlen(item);
        persons[i].id = i;
        strcpy(persons[i].name, item);

        item = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_persons; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s | %d\n", persons[i].id, persons[i].name, persons[i].len_name);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_persons; i++)
    {
        free(persons[i].name);
    }

}
```